# Is there a way to keep an object always at the top of the display list?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to make a display object always be at the top of the display list?

For example, I know you can set the childIndex, i.e:

setChildIndex(myDisplayObject, numChildren-1);

But is there a way that an object has sensed that something else has been added to the display list and restack themselves accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen to the [Event.ADDED](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#ADDED) event on the container. This event will bubble up, so you'll get called whenever a display object is added to the container or any of its children.

Here's an example of how you could do this. You'll see the black box always stays on top.

```
var container:DisplayObjectContainer = this; // this is a frame script but just change this line as necessary
container.addEventListener(Event.ADDED,handleAdded,true);

function handleAdded(e:Event):void {
    // this if tries to cover some edge cases, unlikely to happen in your code, from your description
    if(container == topElement.parent && container.numChildren > 0 && container.getChildIndex(topElement) != container.numChildren - 1) {
        container.setChildIndex(topElement,numChildren - 1);
    }
}

function getSprite(c:uint):Sprite {
    var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
    sp.graphics.beginFill(c);
    sp.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
    sp.graphics.endFill();
    return sp;
}

var topElement:Sprite = getSprite(0);

container.addChild(topElement);
var sp:Sprite = getSprite(0xff0000);
container.addChild(sp);
sp.addChild(getSprite(0xff00));
var sp2:Sprite = getSprite(0xff);
container.addChild(sp2);
```

However, I think it's much simpler and cleaner just to have 2 containers, say, `top` and `bottom`, kind of like layers. In `top` you'd add the element that always must be on top (or this could be your element as you probably don't need to have this extra container). In `bottom` you'd add and remove whatever you want. Then you can forget about manually restacking stuff (at least to keep the top element atop).

Answer (score 3):

You can override the addChild() method in the parent object. In that method you can move your child to the top using

```
setChildIndex(myDisplayObject, numChildren-1);
```

In this way everytime an object is added to the parent, the parent moves your object to the top.

Comment: it's not exactly, my idea is to override addChild() of your container and in just one line of code you can get what you want. I know that you already wrote that line of code, but the keypoint is the place where you put that line :)